# How do I convert "January 30, 2015" to a date object in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, and one of the columns are dates that are stored in the format "month_name day, year" (e.g. "December 25, 2016"). How do I convert these to date objects? Upon searching, I came across the following code:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

But upon viewing the data, the date column is `NA`.

Comment: Your "monthname dayofmonth, year" looks *nothing* like "monthname/dayofmonth/year", leading to the `NA`s. You might find `?strptime` useful, as it contains the percent-codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
as.Date("December 25, 2016", format = '%B %d, %Y')
#[1] "2016-12-25"
```

You need to specify the `format` argument in `as.Date` based on how your dates look like. The full details of all the options are in `?strptime`.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)
mdy("December 25, 2016")

#[1] "2016-12-25"
```

Comment: I agree `lubridate` has some great tools for converting strings to dates.  Just be aware that they will be converted to a separate date format than in base R.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the all inclusive `anytime` package which handles almost all the cases.

```
library(anytime)
anytime("December 25, 2016")

#[1] "2016-12-25 MYT"
```